# cursor returns nothing when scanning for media files

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When i tried to scan the external card using the cursor it returned nothing. Here is  my code,

```
    Cursor mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            mediaColumns, null,null,null);

    // Loop through results
    if ((mediaCursor != null) && mediaCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // Get video id
            int id = mediaCursor.getInt(mediaCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
            // Get the thumbnail associated with the video
            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            Cursor thumbnailCursor = managedQuery(
                    MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    thumbnailColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID
                            + "=" + id, null, null);


            // New movie object from the data
            Moovi movie = new Moovi(mediaCursor, thumbnailCursor);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, movie.toString());
            // Add to movie list
            movieList.add(movie);
        } while (mediaCursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

what is wrong in this code. can anyone suggest a way to fix this

Comment: Are you testing this on Android 4.4 (API level 19)? Does the code work on earlier versions? If so, you might just need the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

Comment: @MichaelMarvick I am testing this on Android 4.2 and i have that permission in my manifest. It has no problem with launching.But it shows empty list

Answer (score 1):

First check if you can get any result from `mediaCursor`. Put only `MediaStore.Video.Media._ID` in columns parameter. Something like this:

```
Cursor mediaCursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[]{MediaStore.Vide.Media._ID}, null,null,null);
```

and then check results.

Did you added

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

in your manifest file?

Comment: @markus m i have added the permission and i changed my code as you said. it wont work.it is showing blank list as before

Comment: are you sure you have sdcard installed/any videos on sdcard?

Comment: yes, i've tested it in my phone too. but the same result